# How to get data about library members who returned their books after a specific period

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to get all the members who returned the borrowed books late. I have a borrowing table, example of books table and the members table.

Which statement should be used to retrieve the data of which members returned books  after more than 30 days?

I hope this a clear explanation. Thanks in advance for your help!

This is the borrowing table:

[image]

This is the members table:

[image]

Comment: Some extra explanation would be nice, like the actual table structures and types and which is the column when they were supposed to return and which was the one where they retured

Comment: Image for the borrowing table is not available and even when it was, it's unclear which column is for the date it was borrowed and the date it was returned

Comment: Sorry because its the first time to upload a question here but i corrected  it you can check the edit version and thanks for the fast answer

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't see the entire column names for the dates and neither the table names and neither the relations between the tables (which is the foreign key to the user table in the borrowings table)

Comment: I added an answer from what I could make of the images, I didn't test it but should work on MySQL.

Comment: Tag the dbms used (too many of them have their own, product specific, date/time functions.) Also add the expected result!

Comment: @Jarlh 
Thanks for your tips and i ll do so but i can't edit my post since i am new here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can make of the images, the following query should work with some modifications:

```
SELECT Us.*, Bo.* FROM Borrowings Bo
    INNER JOIN Users Us
        ON Bo.LID_LIDNUMMER = Us.LIDNUMMER
            WHERE Bo.DATUM_RETURNED - Bo.DATUM_BORROWED > 30
```

Comment: You really understood what i need exactly and i tried this query but i have  missing right parentheses error  

'SELECT l.naam , l.lidnummer,ont.datum_ontleent,ont.datum_terug
FROM ontlening ont  INNER JOIN lid l 
        ON ont.LID_LIDNUMMER = l.LIDNUMMER
            WHERE ADD_DATE(ont.DATUM_ontleent, INTERVAL 30 DAY) < ont.DATUM_terug;'

Comment: Thanks @GGG i appreciate your willing to answer and to help me in finding out the answer i think my data is not clear for you..but   why sql giving me that  datediff  is invalid identifier isn't it a keyword or not...!!

Comment: @walid Which dbms(MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) are you using?

Comment: SQL Server is Microsoft's, I've updated my answer, try again please

Comment: It is very interesting that this solution works for walid, since it finds all the cases when the book was borrowed more than 30 days **after** it was returned.

Comment: @mathguy Yeah, I had an error in my math, it was returning a negative number (which probably wouldn't or at least shouldn't work) since I was subtracting the date it was returned from the date it was borrowed (which obviously returns a negative number). It should work properly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select * from MembersTable MT join BooksTable BT on
MT.IssuedBookId=Bt.BookID Where
DATEDIFF(dd,MT.BookIssuedDate,MT.BookReturnedDate,)>30
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit but what i need is the members not the books so the relation should be between the borrowing table and the member table using the foreign key of the borrowing table which is 'lid_lidnummer',

But thanks any way